# Bootstrap select - remove scrollbar + rounded corners

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a normal Bootstrap select input, but can't figure out how to get rid of the unnecessary scrollbar, nor how to apply the border-radius to the actual dropdown in the select. This had no effect:

```
select {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: try adding css to parent such as `class1 select {} ` like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N8Brx/

Comment: I have `#status-group select { css}  <div class="col-md-2" id="status-group"><select...`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Anyway: `overflow:hidden` on the parent div doesn't help.

Comment: What version of bootstrap and bootstrap-select are you using? The [examples](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) don't have this issue. Also, can you provide the code for the element in your example?

Comment: check this link http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-headers